# Android launching turn-by-turn navigation intent with exact address

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm launching a google maps turn-by-turn navigation intent with address: `Molenlaan 54, 3299 BL Maasdam, The Netherlands`

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Molenlaan 54, 3299 BL Maasdam, The Netherlands");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);`
```

But for some reason in google maps I'm navigated to address: `Molenlaan 34-48, 3299 BL Maasdam, The Netherlands`, which is close but not exactly where I need to be.
Is there away to launch the intent and have google maps navigate me to the exact address I gave it and not one that is close to it?

Comment: Is this address origin or destination of the route?

Comment: are you still having issues on this?